# Check products attibute after place order

Tags: orders, event-observer, product-attribute

I'm making an observer to check after a order is made, if there is any product inside that order that has the `sync` attribute marked as "Yes".

I'm confused about the models and methods I'd use to make it.

Is this the best way to do it? Can someone give me an example of the methods I would need?

Comment: which Magento version you are using?

Comment: version 1.9.3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Magento 1 you can use `sales_convert_quote_to_order` event

```
<sales_convert_quote_to_order>
    <observers>
        <some_alias>
            <class>your_module/observer</class>
            <method>syncSomething</method>
        </some_alias>
    </observers>
</sales_convert_quote_to_order>
```

also in `config.xml` add this to `global` node

```
<sales>
    <quote>
        <item>
            <product_attributes>
                <sync />
            </product_attributes>
        </item>
    </quote>
</sales>
```

Observer.php

```
public function syncSomething(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();
    foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
        if ($item->getProduct()->getSync()) {
            # do something here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my supervisor told me I need to use event "sales_order_place_after"

Comment: @Stordon have you tested it? I guess it works. `sales_order_place_after` can work too, then observer has to be adjusted ... `$order = $observer->getOrder();` ...

Comment: Gonna test both! Thank you very much. I didn't quite understand why "getSync()", could you explain it to me? You're getting the attribute "sync", but how come it is a method?

Comment: `$prod->getSync()` is just a magic getter method for product attributes. It's same as `$prod->getData('sync')`. And if you say "set to YES" i guess attribute will return 0 or 1.

Comment: I see!!!! Thank you. Yes, its a boolean attribute. If I'm gonna use sales_order_place_after, I also need to update my config.xml, right?

Comment: For `sales_order_place_after` 2nd part of config.xml shouldn't be required. Btw ... can you ask your supervisor  why he prefers this event? I'm just curious ... :)

Comment: He said its a pattern we follow inside our company. Your way worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create an observer for handling the event after checkout an order.

File **app\code\YourNameSpace\YourModule\etc\events.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="acommerce_utm_after_checkout_event" instance="YourNameSpace\YourModule\Observer\SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver" />
</event>
```

After that, create file **app\code\YourNameSpace\YourModule\Observer\SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver.php**:

```
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
    * @param EventObserver $observer
    * @throws \Exception
    */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {

        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        $products = $order->getAllItems();

       foreach ($products as $product) {
            $check = $product->getCustomAttribute('sync');
            //$check = $product->getSync();
            // Check your value here
       }
    }
}
```

Note: Remember to **clean cache**, and run command **setup:upgrade** in order for the event to work.