# Add value to database after event

Tags: magento-1.9, database, orders

I need to add a value to a table after an event. I made a observer to check if a custom boolean attribute of a product in a order is marked as "yes" and, if it is, I need to add the order's id to this table that I created.

I cant find a tutorial about this anywhere :(

**DONE** -- See edit in the end

my table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `allnations_orders` (
   `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `order` int,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
   )"
);
```

my observer (don't mind the comments in portuguese, they're just for my better understanding)

```
class Novapc_AllNations_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer 
/* not sure if should extend this? */

{
    public function checkOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $event)
    {
        // Carrega a order e o model pra interação com o banco
        $order = $event->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $model = Mage::getModel('novapc_allnations/order');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

        // Variavel pra controlar se vai salvar ou não no banco
        $save = 0;

        // Loop pra ler todos os produtos do pedido
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {

            // Pega o ID do produto
            $product->load($this->getProduct($item)->getId());

            //  Verifica se o produto esta sincronizado com a All Nations
            if ($product->getData('allnations_sync') == 1) {
                $orderId = $order->getId();
                $save = 1;
            }
        }

        // Se algum dos  produtos for da All Nations, salvar o ID do pedido
        if ($save == 1) {
            $model->setOrder($orderId);
            $model->save();
        }
    }
}
```

my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Novapc_Allnations>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Novapc_Allnations>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <novapc_allnations>
                        <class>Novapc_Allnations_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkOrder</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </novapc_allnations>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
        <models>
            <novapc_allnations>
                <class>Novapc_Allnations_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>novapc_allnations_resource</resourceModel>
            </novapc_allnations>
            <novapc_allnations_resource>
                <class>Novapc_Allnations_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <order>
                        <table>allnations_orders</table>
                    </order>
                </entities>
            </novapc_allnations_resource>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <novapc_allnations>
                <class>Novapc_Allnations_Block</class>
            </novapc_allnations>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <novapc_allnations>
                <class>Novapc_Allnations_Helper</class>
            </novapc_allnations>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <novapc_allnations_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Novapc_Allnations</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </novapc_allnations_setup>
            <novapc_allnations_setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </novapc_allnations_setup>
            <novapc_allnations_setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </novapc_allnations_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <inchoo>
                                            <title>Inchoo - All</title>
                                        </inchoo>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Edit -- 
Changed my Observer php to this and it worked:

```
class Novapc_AllNations_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function checkOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $event)
    {
        // Carrega a order e o model pra interação com o banco
        $order = $event->getEvent()->getOrder();

        // Variavel pra controlar se vai salvar ou não no banco
        $save = 0;

        $orderItemIds = array();
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $orderItemIds[] = $item->getProductId();
        }

        $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderItemIds))
            ->addFieldToFilter('allnations_sync', array('eq' => 1))
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        // Loop pra ler todos os produtos do pedido
        if ($productCollection->getSize() >= 1) {
            $save = 1;
        }

    // Se algum dos  produtos for da All Nations, salvar o ID do pedido
        if ($save == 1) {
            $model = Mage::getModel('novapc_allnations/order');
            $orderId = $order->getId();
            $model->setOrder($orderId);
            $model->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code that you already have?

Comment: In which table you need to enter value? Is it magento default or your custom one?

Comment: Added my observer and config.xml and made my question clearer. I need to add to my custom table

Comment: can you share your table structure

Comment: `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT and  `order` int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Stordon, do not load models in a loop ... this is n°1 performance killer ...

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    ...
}
```

Better add the attributes you need before *([see last question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188722/check-products-attibute-after-place-order))*. For saving data to anther table, Abhishek Panchals **2nd way** is the right one. Add your table to config - if it is a custom table, add a model for it and use `$model->save()` instead of a raw SQL query.

---

**Edit:** if you use a custom table you have to add it to `config.xml`, change

```
        <novapc_allnations_resource>
            <class>novapc_AllNations_Model_Resource</class>
        </novapc_allnations_resource>
```

to

```
        <novapc_allnations_resource>
            <class>novapc_AllNations_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <yourmodel>
                    <table>your_table_name</table>
                </yourmodel>
            </entities>
        </novapc_allnations_resource>
```

In your `Model/Yourmodel.php`

```
public function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('novapc_allnations/yourmodel');
}
```

In `Model/Resource/Yourmodel.php`

```
public function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('novapc_allnations/yourmodel', 'your_autoincrement_column');
}
```

In `Model/Resource/Yourmodel/Collection.php`

```
public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('novapc_allnations/yourmodel');
}
```

Now you should be able to get/set data from/to your custom table.

```
$model = Mage::getModel('novapc_allnations/yourmodel');
$model->setSomeValue(value);
$model->save();
```

---

*Note: your class names should start with uppercase char (`<class>novapc_AllNations_...</class>`)*

Comment: I see!! Thanks for the advice. But it isn't working... I think I'm just too dumb to work with Magento

Comment: @Stordon updated, maybe it helps.

Comment: Didn't work too, I think I'm doing something wrong in my config.xml or in my Observer

Comment: @Stordon please post Obersver.php ...

Comment: updated both my Observer.php and my config.xml... Now also when I click Place order in checkout page it doesn't load, it just keeps in that same page :( I'm using Models, and just like the ones you posted

Comment: @Stordon This seems wrong to me `$product->load($this->getProduct($item)->getId());`, please try this instead `$product->load($item->getProductId());` or `$product->load($item->getProduct()->getId());`

Comment: yeah, that line seems to be the problem. I put // in front of it and the order went ok. Tried both your ways, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Hope it helps :)

**First way without model**

```
$orderId = $order->getId();
$resource     = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$writeAdapter   = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$table        = $resource->getTableName('your_table_name');
$query        = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`order_id`) VALUES ($orderId);";
$writeAdapter->query($query);
```

**Second way using model**

```
$orderId = $order->getId();
$model = Mage::getModel('your_model_name'); //for eg. Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

try {
    $model->setOrderId($orderId);
    $model->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: both ways didn't work :(